# Django: ForeignKey set to default null (author_id)=(0) error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django 1.11.1 and python3. Can not set `author` field to default null. What can be wrong?

```
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', null=True, blank=True, db_constraint=False)
```

error:

```
DETAIL:  Key (author_id)=(0) is not present in table "auth_user"
```

Comment: Have you ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` after adding this new field?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Looks like there might be a row where the `author_id` field is set to 0 and there isn't a auth_user with an id of 0. Login to your database and query the table that you have `author_id` and see if there is any rows where the value is set to 0.

Comment: Come on, man. Everybody knows there is no `id=0` in `auth_user`. The problem is how to add new model without referencing to existing object.

Comment: I created a model with the exact args and kwargs you've given in the question and i'm able to create new records without a User. There must be something else that's causing this that's not in this question.

Comment: Very weird. Thank you for try.

Comment: Amazing thing: I have removed `author` field from model and still there is an error! How might it be? Like caching..

Comment: Fixed: I had to clean all past migration files and migrate again

Answer (score 0):

Fix: remove all past migration files that are about `author` field and `migrate` again